# cx_freeze error "cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named Console"

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm trying to convert a python 3.4 program of mine into an exe for distribution. I tried using cx_Freeze to do this. However, when I run python setup.py build with this setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup( name = "Converter" ,
   version = "0.1" ,
   description = "" ,
   executables = [Executable("filename.py")] , )
```

I get this error code:

```
C:\Python34>python setup.py build
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    executables = [Executable("helloworld.py")] , )
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 362, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 231, in run
    metadata = metadata)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 136, in __init__
    self._VerifyConfiguration()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 504, in _VerifyConfiguration
    self._GetBaseFileName()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 239, in _GetBaseFileName
    raise ConfigError("no base named %s", name)
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named Console
```

This same error code occurs when I try to setup for a hello world file. So it has nothing to do with my script.

Any help? This is the first time I've used cx_Freeze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this line is failing `argsSource.base = self._GetFileName("bases", name, ext)` which means that it can't find that file, which makes sense. Check this folder `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases` for `Console.exe`. If you don't have that then try reinstalling cx_freeze. That's my directory for python. I would assume yours is in the same place but if not just search for it

Comment: The firewall at my job seems to have blocked all of the files in the \bases directory and replaced them with warning .txt files. So that's great. Time to find another work around.

Comment: I battle with that issue a lot at my work. It's very frustrating

Comment: The holes I jumped through just download the install for cx freeze was enough already.

Comment: I was able to get the needed files by downloading the python wheel found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=cx_Freeze&version=4.3.4 and replacing the warnings with them.

Answer (score -2):

Just type in cmd "pip uninstall cx_Freeze" for uninstall cx_Freeze and again reinstall it by type "pip install cx_Freeze".

Comment: This is the most basic thing that a developer tries with any library. When you are answering please come-up with something concrete.